# Dynamic sender loaded with ampscript from within email - possible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, send-definition

I am sending a dynamically populated email to people who sign up in a form.
Based on country I want to send it with the country specific "From name" / "From email".

I need to do the logic from within the email. 
Is that possible?

Like this in the email:

```
if @countrycode == 'en-en' then
set @FromName = 'Business name'
set @FromEmail = 'business@email.com'
(else ... = use default)
```

I have a Send Classification called "Dynamic Sender".
There I point to the sender profile called "Dynamic_Sender" and there I have:
From Name: %%FromName%%
From email: %%FromEmail%%

Yet in the preview of my test email, I can't see the From Name and From Email are not populating.

Somewhere I saw that you need to add FromName and FromEmail as profile attribute, but surely that is only if you intend to populate from a data extension?

Ideas on how to populate the sender stuff from within the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is personalization is done with Personalization String (field merges). You would either have to add them to the Profile Attributes or have a fields in the send data extensions that contain the Column Header `From Name` and `From Email`

Comment: So there would be no way to set From name and From Email from within an email?

Comment: Not that I know of